# Is it idiomatic to write: "He rides to the farm by bike."?

Tags: idioms

Is it idiomatic to write: "He rides to the farm by bike."?  In my opinion, you'd rather write "He goes to the farm by bike" or "He rides his bike to the farm".

Comment: He bikes to the farm. He walks to the farm.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not idiomatic to say "ride by bike".  Riding is how one travels on a bike, so *ride by bike* sounds strangely redundant.

[Google Ngrams shows how much less common "*ride* by bike" is than other "*verb* by bike" phrasings.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*_VERB%20by%20bike%2Cride_INF%20by%20bike&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

I suspect that some of the "ride by bike" examples that it has found are actually from sentences like "It is two hours' *ride by bike*", where *ride* is actually a noun.

Comment: Unless it's a reaction to the statement that "he" is "riding to the farm", perhaps? To emphasize *how* he is riding?

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for your answer.

Comment: There is no special emphasis intended in this sentence. It is just a statement that the person doesn't use public transport to go to the inner city farm he works for, unlike some colleagues who go there by bus.

Comment: I find the sentence to be idiomatic. Yes, it might be redundant, but not if we assume that there are other ways to ride to the farm. (Perhaps there are a horse and a tractor nearby.) (This is along the lines of what @Joachim is saying.)

Comment: I agree with you that _He rides his bike to the farm_ is much more idiomatic - or _He goes to the farm on his bike_.

Answer (score -1):

This is pretty interesting actually.

If you said, "He travels to the farm by *train*" that would be 100% correct. When you travel on a train, you travel *by* train. You might travel *on* a train, but in the context of how you got to a place, if you got there via a train, you would say you got there "by train."

But that's not the case with a bicycle. You would simply say, "He bicycles to the farm."

English has a very strange habit of *creating* verbs from nouns. Bicycle is a noun. "He has a bicycle. It is red." The word was created to describe the thing.

Bicycle is *also* a verb. "He bicycles all over town. He doesn't like cars." We sort of made that up after the fact to describe people doing bicycle things.

So logically, you'd think a sentence like, "He bicycles his bicycle all over town" would work, but it doesn't. Instead you would say, "He *rides* his bicycle all over town."

"Ride" is of course the proper verb for this sort of activity and "He rides his bike to the farm" would be perfectly correct. You can replace "bike" in that sentence with any rideable thing: horse, motorcycle, hamster...And it will still make sense (might be a *big* hamster).

But, because bicycle is a "verbed noun", you can also say, absolutely correctly, "He bicycled to the farm" where you couldn't say "He horsed to the farm" or "He hamstered to the farm" (you *could* say "He motorcycled to the farm", though that's less common).

Just English being weird.

Comment: Is "he bicycles to the farm" idiomatic? More importantly, is "he rides to the farm by bike" idiomatic? The latter is the question here, and you don't seem to answer it :)

Comment: He **cycles** to work. The most common verb is "cycle".